# How to create a view with different column names than source table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that stores email data.  The challenge that I have is that some of the column names use MSSQL Reserved Words such as To and FROM.

I've place brackets around the column names and my Query works fine in Query Designer, but the challenge is I'll be calling it from ASP.Net.  Bracket syntax in ASP.Net indicate it should inject data in place of the brackets.

To avoid all of this I want to create a View.  How do I change the column names in the View to avoid Reserved Words?

```
SELECT        PortalID, [To], [From], Subject, Body, CreatedOnDate, CreatedByUserID
FROM            dbo.CoreMessaging_Messages
```

Comment: `create view v (c1, c2, ...) as select ...`

Comment: The same you do in a any Select: `[To] AS newname`

Comment: Thanks @dnoeth. That worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

In a view, you can do:

```
create view v_table as
    select PortalID, [To] as to_whatever, [From] as from_whatever,
           Subject, Body, CreatedOnDate, CreatedByUserID
    from dbo.CoreMessaging_Messages;
```

A simpler method might be just to use computed columns:

```
alter table dbo.CoreMessaging_Messages
        add to_whatever as ([To]);

alter table dbo.CoreMessaging_Messages
        add from_whatever as ([From]);
```

Then the alternate names are available to whoever uses to the table.